# How to find the number of entries in the .dynamic section of an ELF file?

Tags: c, elf, readelf

Can there be a method determining the number of entries in the .dynamic section of an ELF file without using the readelf utility? I am trying to output data from the .dynamic section using the `gelf_getdyn()` function, but cannot figure out a way of programmatically finding the number of entries in this section. Any help or webpages that can help (cannot find the source code for `readelf`) would be extremely appreciative.

Comment: readelf is part of binutils, look at that for the source.

Answer (score 1):

> cannot figure out a way of programmatically finding the number of entries in this section

You simply iterate over all entries until you encounter an entry with `d_tag == DT_NULL`. That entry terminates the array. [Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/819-0690/chapter6-42444.html).